# Get Android soft keyboard 'Done' button appear in web SPA

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html

I am writing a SPA Web Application using AngularJS (not using Ionic) and I have a form that looks like this.

```
<form ng-submit="submit(myData);">
    <textarea name="myDataTextArea" id="myDataTextArea" ng-model="myData"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
</form>
```

When I click the textarea in my phone (Samsung Galaxy 6 Edge, with Android 6.0.1, Marshsmallow) I get this keyboard:

[image: No DONE button]

Since I do not necessarily need users to be able to use the return to break lines, I tried capturing the return/enter keyCode like this:

```
$('#myDataTextArea').bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        submit();
    }
});
```

But that did not work either. How can I have Android give me this?

[image: Gå is Swedish for Go]

Comment: In java code, you'd simply apply an imeOption specifying the done button.  I'm not sure if that's possible in angular, as it isn't an option in html, so the browser can't know and just sends default options.  As for the key down issue-  soft keyboards don't send key events.  Are you getting key events for any key?

Comment: I'd also point out that if you really want total and easy control over a platform-  don't write a web app.  Web apps generally only support the lowest common denominator between platforms.

Comment: "As for the key down issue- soft keyboards don't send key events", actually they do and I got it working using addEventListener and _keydown_ event. But it still is not the best option, I would like to use the actual GO button and I hear you about web apps. Naturally I work in a context where it is necessary to write a web app and I leave it at that. I have seen other web applications/sites using the GO buttons in forms so I know it is possible.

Comment: They don't-  I wrote one of the most popular keyboards for Android.  There might be something in Angular or the browser faking them though.  Android Key events are hardware buttons only (a software keyboard *can* send them, but it would be very unusual).

Comment: I don´t even use angular in this aspect, I use the following _plain JavaScript_ `document.getElementById("myDataTextArea").addEventListener("keydown", function (e) { [.. code ..] });` and it works, so from somewhere the keydown event is sent.